# Meteor session object not working reactively

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have two pages, `fila.js` and `retirada.js`.

`fila.js` contains a function called `atualizarChamadas` that I  export to `retirada.js`.

When I call the function from `fila.js` it works fine, but when I call it in `retirada.js` the session object or reactive-var doesn't  work reactively in the helper.

My function that are in `fila.js`:

```
export default function atualizarChamadas() {
    let chamadas = Chamadas.find({medico: 1},{sort: {data_inicio: -1}}).fetch();
    //Session.set("chamadas", chamadas);
    ChamadasReactive.set(chamadas);
}
```

My templates helpers

```
    Template.fila.helpers({
    chamadasAtendimento: function() {
        //return Session.get("chamadas");
        return ChamadasReactive.get().filter((el)=>{
            return el.status == 'A';
        }).slice(0,11);
      }
});

Template.fila.helpers({
    chamadasEspera: function() {
        //return Session.get("chamadas");

        return ChamadasReactive.get().filter((el)=>{
            return el.status == 'E';
        }).slice(0, 11);
      }
});

Template.fila.helpers({
    chamadasFinalizada: function() { 
        return ChamadasReactive.get().filter((el)=>{
            return el.status == 'F';
        }).slice(0, 11);
      }
});
```

In `fila.js` I call the function and it works fine:

```
    Template.fila.events({
        "submit form": function (e, template){
            e.preventDefault();
            atualizarChamadas();
        }

});
```

I have this blaze template that works fine when the functions is called from `fila.js`:

```
<tbody>  
        {{#each chamada in chamadasEspera}}
            <tr class="success">
                <td>{{chamada.senha}}</td>
                <td>{{chamada.data_inicio}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="{{chamada._id}}" class="form-control">
                        <option value="E">Esperando</option>
                        <option value="A">Atendimento</option>
                        <option value="F">Finalizado</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><button id="{{chamada._id}}" value="{{chamada.senha}}" name="{{chamada.status}}" class="btn btn-block">Chamar</button></td>

            </tr>
         {{/each}}
    </tbody>


    <br/>

    <tbody>
    {{#each chamada in chamadasAtendimento}}
            <tr class="danger">
                <td>{{chamada.senha}}</td>
                <td>{{chamada.data_inicio}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="{{chamada._id}}"  class="form-control">
                        <option value="A">Atendimento</option>
                        <option value="E">Esperando</option>
                        <option value="F">Finalizado</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><button id="{{chamada._id}}" value="{{chamada.senha}}"  name="{{chamada.status}}" class="btn btn-block">Chamar</button></td>
             </tr>
     {{/each}}
    </tbody>

    <br/>
    <tbody>
    {{#each chamada in chamadasFinalizada}}
        <tr class="info">
            <td>{{chamada.senha}}</td>
            <td>{{chamada.data_inicio}}</td>
            <td>{{chamada.data_fim}}</td>
            <td>
                <select id="{{chamada._id}}"  class="form-control">
                    <option value="F">Finalizada</option>
                    <option value="E">Esperando</option>
                    <option value="A">Atendimento</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
     </tbody>
  </table>
  {{/if}}
```

In my page `retirada.js` I have this code that calls `atualizarChamadas`, but it does not work reactively:

```
 Template.retirada.events({
    "click button": function(e,template){
        let newPass = e.target.id,
            id = Retirada.find({}).fetch()[0]._id;

        console.log('01:' + Chamadas.find({medico: 1},{sort: {data_inicio: -1}}).fetch().length);

        Retirada.update(id, {count: newPass});
        Chamadas.insert(
            {senha: newPass, status : 'E', data_inicio: new Date(), medico: 1});

        console.log('02:' + Chamadas.find({medico: 1},{sort: {data_inicio: -1}}).fetch().length);

        setTimeout (teste, 1000);

        function teste(){
            atualizarChamadas();
        }
    }
     });
```

When the `console.log` is called, I can see the length of object result of chamadas increased, but my template does not refresh the new data. I was used methods to change the document, but I change it for doing on the view, but still does not work.

I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue comes from using a Meteor call inside the event handler. Here's a couple of alternative packages that allow for reactive method calls: [meteor-reactive-method](https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-reactive-method) and [mnmtanish:call](https://atmospherejs.com/mnmtanish/call).

Comment: I stopped use methods to call, now I change the mongo document directly on the view, but it still does not work

Comment: I have generally gotten around these issues by changing the view directly with jquery in Meteor calls. I will update my answer.

Comment: Just noticed you changed the code. Are you using Iron Router? You could return the cursor (Chamadas.find() as a part of the data of the route). This works pretty reliably. If you need filters, Session variables work will within the data context of iron router. Let me know if you need more info on how to do this. For security reasons, you should still use the Meteor call on the server-side and block insert/update/remove operations form the client side.

Comment: I changed the code trying to be more clear for understand, I removed the methods call and I use iron-router too, I will try to use Iron to return my collections and come back again, thanks!

Comment: I used the data that comes from iron in template.rendered and it works fine, but only in the first reload, how can do it from another page?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue with this block of code, I used collections directly in helper return and reactivity works again  whenever my collection change.

```
Template.fila.helpers({
    chamadasAtendimento: function() {
        //return Session.get("chamadas");
        return Chamadas.find({medico: 1},{sort: {data_inicio: -1}}).fetch().filter((el)=>{
            return el.status == 'A';
        }).slice(0,11);
      }
});

Template.fila.helpers({
    chamadasEspera: function() {
        return Chamadas.find({medico: 1},{sort: {data_inicio: -1}}).fetch().filter((el)=>{
            return el.status == 'E';
        }).slice(0, 11);
      }
});

Template.fila.helpers({
    chamadasFinalizada: function() { 
        return Chamadas.find({medico: 1},{sort: {data_inicio: -1}}).fetch().filter((el)=>{
            return el.status == 'F';
        }).slice(0, 11);
      }
});
```